# How to compare datetimes in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes like this:

```
time  .. ...
2019-05-01 10:50:21
2019-05-01 10:50:22
2019-05-01 10:50:23
..
```

and another one in the same row:

```
from  to
2019-05-01 10:50:21 2019-05-01 10:55:21
```

I imported dataframes from two different .csv and converted timestamp with pd.to_datetime

I want to delete all cells in df1 where df1.time is included in df1.from and df2.to.

```
if df1.time > df2.from and df2.time < df2.to
  delete
```

How could I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your first dataframe starts at `2019-05-01 10:50:21` and ends at `2019-05-01 10:55:30`. Let's create here the two dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.date_range("2019-05-01 10:50:21", "2019-05-01 10:55:50", freq='s')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': a})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "from": ["2019-05-01 10:50:21", "2019-05-01 10:55:30"], 
    "to": ["2019-05-01 10:55:21", "2019-05-01 10:55:45"]}, 
    index=[0, 1]
    ).apply(lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s))
```

We can use a `date_range` to create each intermediary datetime value, and then check if each value of the first dataframe belongs to this range:

```py
dt_ranges = [pd.date_range(row['from'], row['to'], freq='s') for _, row in df2.iterrows()]
dt_rng = pd.concat([pd.Series(ix) for ix in dt_ranges])

mask = df1.isin(dt_rng.values)
filtered = df1[~mask].dropna()
print(filtered)
```

```py
                   time
301 2019-05-01 10:55:22
302 2019-05-01 10:55:23
303 2019-05-01 10:55:24
304 2019-05-01 10:55:25
305 2019-05-01 10:55:26
306 2019-05-01 10:55:27
307 2019-05-01 10:55:28
308 2019-05-01 10:55:29
325 2019-05-01 10:55:46
326 2019-05-01 10:55:47
327 2019-05-01 10:55:48
328 2019-05-01 10:55:49
329 2019-05-01 10:55:50
```

Comment: Sorry, I explain better my question. In df1.time there is a row for each second for 24 hours, and I want to remove all the cells in df1 included in the interval df2.from and df2.to for each row of df2.

Comment: @andrea_r94 Ok I see, then it's the same mechanism only for multiple ranges. I'm editing the answer

Comment: @andrea_r94 I edited the answer to take multiple rows of df2 into account.